# why submodule path error occur even there're no submodule?

Tags: github, svelte

I am currently creating a high school placement program.
After completing the source code, I tried to use GitHub for distribution.
However, the following error occurred during build.

```
  Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'high_school_simulater' in .gitmodules
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

To solve the error, I tried to find the .gitmodules and find the nodemodule but there was no .gitmodules.
Next, I entered `git rm -f 'high_school_simulater'`
and result was `fatal: could not lookup name for submodule 'high_school_simulater'`

Is the way I tried wrong? Or is there another problem? My GitHub address is below, so if you have any questions, please go there and take a look.

https://github.com/Captinkkang/high_school_simulater

To solve the error, I tried to find the .gitmodules and find the nodemodule but there was no .gitmodules.
Next, I entered `git rm -f 'high_school_simulater'`
and the result was `fatal: could not lookup name for submodule 'high_school_simulater'`

Is the method I tried wrong? Or is there another problem? My GitHub address is below, so if you have any questions, please go there and take a look and answer about how to solve the error.

https://github.com/Captinkkang/high_school_simulater

*caution* My source code is pretty dirty. Still, if possible, please reply with a solution to the problem rather than advice about the code. thank you